# Do-while loop jumps over first string from array

Tags: c++, arrays, do-while

So, I created a program that will allow a user enter some string values from an array.

So, that's my code:

```
int i = 0;
string elements[100] = {};
do {
    cout << "Element [" << i << "]: ";
    getline(cin, elements[i]);
    i++;
} while (elements[i - 1] != "_END");
```

The problem is, when I run the program, `do while` skips the first element of the array.

That's the output:

[image]

You can see that `elements[0]` is skipped. Tried same code but replaced `getline` with a simple `cin`. It worked. But I need `getline`.

What can I do?

Comment: You cannot add elements to a static array. Use `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Comment: @hnefatl The original code was `string elements[100] = {};` Edited the code from the post.

Comment: @Jarod42 are you sure the size is 1? [And not 0?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d3fa3e80d036170)

Comment: Did you set one of the string elements to "_END"?

Comment: @Zebrafish Nope. If the user will enter `_END`, the counting will stop. So, he won't need to write new string values for the array anymore.

Comment: OK. now you just snuck in a change that invalidates most of the comments.

Comment: @pm100 Yeah. My fault.

Comment: @pm100 that's fine -- comments are volatile. Invalidating answers is what's uncool.

Comment: @pm100 I don't want the element to be printed. I just want the program to print the number of the element he needs to insert.

Comment: @hnefatl Yes, but my code is a little bit complicated. This `do while` loop is nested in another `do while` loop. The user needs to type at first a command. If he types in `_ENTER`, the loop mentioned in the question will be executed.

Comment: The code you've shown should do exactly what you expect, so the problem is in the code you haven't shown. Post the smallest example you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem.

Comment: Most likely, there is already input waiting in `cin` before this code is run, such as an unread line break, so the first loop iteration reads that input, and then the second iteration has to wait for the user to enter more input.

Answer (score 0):

Proper solution would be to use a C++ container like `std::vector<T>` when you want to insert unknown amount of elements into a list.

Try to add the `cin.ignore()`command before calling getline. The issue with your code is that first time `getline` is called there is something in `cin` stream that immediately is read.

```
unsigned i = 0;
vector<string> elements;
string newElement;
cin.ignore(); // You need to empty the cin stream first
do {
    cout << "Element [" << i << "]: ";
    getline(cin, newElement); // Reads text from input
    elements.push_back(newElement); // Appends new element to the back of vector
    ++i;
} while (newElement != "End_");
```

Feel free to ask if you have any questions about this code example.

**Edit:** Your last comment about writing nested while loop and entering some commands with `getline` before this example code seems to be the issue I've mentioned above.

**Edit2:** The `cin.ignore()` should actually be called just once before the loop so it clear any unwated data from `cin` and not in every loop iteration. The provided example is tested and works now.

Comment: nope - same issue. Although i would always say 'use std::vector'

Comment: Oh i know where the problem is. You need to clean the output stream because the getline will load the cout output. Let me find how to do this properly.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah sorry I wrote this directly in here and not in any IDE

Comment: When starting the program the cin stream will be empty, it will block at ignore(). Is that what's intended?

Comment: when you call the getline, its first parameter tells it where to read from and the second parameter tells it where to save the data. Since he was using the cin stream before, when getline was called for the first time, it read last thing that was in cin.

Comment: I've edited my answer and tested the code myself. The problem was in getline reading some old input from `cin` the first time it was called.